# Google Calendar SSL error when authenticating

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, calendar

I have SSL enabled on my server and in my php build.  when i run the following code

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
$user = '********';
$pass = '********';
$service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; 
try {
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user,$pass,$service);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception caught: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

I get the following error message

> Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #1: Operation not permitted

any ideas how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error #1: Operation not permitted

Something such as a local firewall or policy system like SELinux is preventing you from opening a socket connection.

You'll want to get in contact with your host or sysadmin and ask them to investigate.  It's worth noting that many low-cost shared hosting providers frequently block outgoing connections.

Comment: thanks.. I contacted my hosting provider and they had to add an exception for ssl and tcp to their firewall for me